# Dovecot: "Failed to write to main log (No space left on device)"

Tags: centos, email, dovecot

Every single morning, my dovecot service goes down and i need to start it again, and it is repeating day by day, so i was looking for some clue to find out why it was coming down, and i found that errors on the **/var/log/maillog** file:

```
"failed to write to main log: length=165 result=-1 errno=28 (No space left on device)"
"write failed on panic log: length=122 result=-1 errno=28 (No space left on device)"
```

And i see that the time when this error was displayed was the same time that the service goes down, so i see it as the reason of the problem.

By the way, i really dont know what is happening because when i type: `df -h`  i can see:

```
Filesystem    Size    Used    Avail    Use%    Mounted on
/dev/vda1     30G      27G     1.9G     94%    /
tmpfs         499M       0     499M      0%    /dev/shm
```

So the disk isnt full, and why this "no space left on device" warning ? I dont know what to try.

**Note:** this error started to happen since 2 weeks ago, but my server is running since more than 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

That's all because `df` and `du` calculated used/free space in a different way. `df` count space used by files in the hierarchy while `du` counts FS's inodes.

If you have rotated logfile already opened by some process, that process continues to write to the old file not the new one, because filedescriptor is associated with inode not the filename. So you have write into the file that seems to be "rotated away" days ago, but its inodes are still in use and file grow and grow until free inodes will be exhausted.

For the proper behavior you have to restart process after his logfile has been rotated. The other approach is to use `syslog` instead of logging directly into the file.

Keep in mind that problem shouldn't be related with `dovecot` but rather with every single software with intensive logging like `apache`.

Comment: I already did that, i did setup a CRON that restarts the service every morning, by the way, sometimes it does not work, probably because the service was gone twice, so i need to have a solution to solve this problem, how i can do that? the only one solution cant be restarting the service, can it?

Comment: You have to restart your services one by one and check whether the space will be released after some service being restarted.

Comment: But the space isnt full at now, and i dont know when it becomes full or it really goes full.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pl check free inode numbers

> df -i

If it is 100% full than remove some of those

Comment: the inodes `IUse%` are at 22% at the moment, but i dont know how it was on the moment of the error.